# How to pass a string from an activity to a non activity class in the same activity in android

Tags: java, android

In my project i got a string from one activity to other ListActivity.now i want to get this string to my adapter class.how can i do this..
below is my code, in this i want to get the fromMobileno string to my adapter class

```
    public  class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
        ListView lv;
        Cursor cursor;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_contact);
            cursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            String[] from={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
            int[] to={R.id.name_entry,R.id.number_entry};

            adapterlistadapter=new adapter(this,R.layout.single_row1,cursor,from,to);
            setListAdapter(listadapter);

            lv=getListView();
            lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String fromMobileno = extras.getString("KEY");



        }

        @Override()
        public long getSelectedItemId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getSelectedItemId();
        }

        @Override
        public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
        }
        class adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements Filterable {
            private Context context;

            private int layout;
            public adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                    String[] from, int[] to) {
                super(context, layout, c, from, to);
                this.context=context;
                this.layout=layout;

                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            }


            @Override
            public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

                ....


        }
}
```

Comment: have you ever heard about constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to get this string to my adapter class.how can i do this

Add one more String parameter to `adapter` which to get required value from class:

```
 String strfromMobileno="";
 public adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                    String[] from, int[] to,String fromMobileno) {
     super(context, layout, c, from, to);
     ///... your code here 
     strfromMobileno=fromMobileno;
  }
```

and on `onCreate` method get value from intent before creating object of `adapter` class.

And another way is because `adapter` is inner class of `MainActivity` class so you can also access outer class variables in inner class.declare `fromMobileno` as class level variable instead of inside `onCreate` method then use `MainActivity.this.fromMobileno` to access `fromMobileno` in `adapter` class